# How to Serialize Arc<Mutex<T>> in Rust?

Tags: rust, serde

I have a trait `DataSet`, for which I've implemented `Serialize` like so:

```
impl Serialize for dyn DataSet {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        let mut seq = serializer.serialize_map(Some(2))?;
        seq.serialize_entry("fields", "Hello")?;
        seq.serialize_entry("measures", "There")?;
        seq.end()
    }
}
```

Now, in program/application I am sharing pointer to the trait object:

```
let x: Arc<Mutex<dyn DataSet>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(data));
```

Where `data` is any object which implements DataSet.

Now, I want to turn this object into json (ie serialize it):

```
serde_json::to_string(&x)
```

It works for `Box` instead of `Arc<Mutex<>>`. But with `Arc<Mutex<>>` compiler complains:

```
the size for values of type `dyn base_engine::DataSet` cannot be known at compilation time
the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `dyn base_engine::DataSet`
the trait `Serialize` is implemented for `Arc<T>`
required because of the requirements on the impl of `Serialize` for `Mutex<dyn base_engine::DataSet>`
```

I've tried adding feature `["rc"]` to serde, but this didn't help.

Comment: It's hard to believe that with `"rc"` you get the **exact** same error message.

Comment: @Finomnis The problem is not the `Arc`, it's that serde has (implicit) `Sized` bounds on `Mutex`. I'm preparing a PR.

Comment: Interesting that it works at all (like, with `Box`). My intuition would have said you can't serialize a `dyn`. But I guess you just can't *deserialize* a `dyn`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** Since serde 1.0.145 this code works.

---

**Original answer:**

Serde doesn't support serializing a `Mutex` with unsized type. [I sent a PR to relax this](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/pull/2282), but in the meantime you can use a newtype:

```rust
pub struct MutexWrapper<T: ?Sized>(pub Mutex<T>);

impl<T: ?Sized + Serialize> Serialize for MutexWrapper<T> {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        self.0
            .lock()
            .expect("mutex is poisoned")
            .serialize(serializer)
    }
}

let x: Arc<MutexWrapper<dyn DataSet>> = Arc::new(MutexWrapper(Mutex::new(data)));
```

You still need to enable the `rc` feature of `serde`, of course.

Comment: Thank you! It might be another question, but the functionality of  [erased_serde](https://docs.rs/erased-serde/latest/erased_serde/trait.Serialize.html) seems to be closely related to my usecase, however I couldn't figure out any benefit of ussing it. Can `erased_serde`  be useful in my situation?

Comment: @AnatolyBugakov No. `erased-serde` allows you to use `dyn Serialize`, but you don't need that.